# How to fill the missing columns with some static values in if-else condition under a function call

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement

How to put some values in the missing columns, as you guys see the below code is working but in the in `else` condition it not filling the column values.

What i need to do to put the `somevalues` in missing areas. Specially i want to fill like `nologin?`.

```
#!/bin/bash
###########
printf "\n"
marker=$(printf "%0.s-" {1..73})
printf "|$marker|\n"
printf "| %-15s | %-15s | %-35s |\n"  "Hostname" "RedHat Vesrion" "Perl Version"
printf "|$marker|\n"

remote_connect() {
   target_host=$1
   remote_data=($(
   ssh -i /home/nxf59093/.ssh/ssh_prod "root@${target_host}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no "
        rhelInfo=\$(cat /etc/redhat-release | awk 'END{print \$7}')
        perlInfo=\$(rpm -qa | grep -i mod_perl)
        echo \$rhelInfo \$perlInfo
                "))

   rhelInfo=${remote_data[0]}
   perlInfo=${remote_data[1]}

   if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
   then
     printf "| %-15s | %-15s | %-35s |\n" "$target_host" "$rhelInfo" "$perlInfo"
   else
     printf "| %-15s | %-15s | %-35s |\n" "$target_host" "?" "?"
fi
}  2>/dev/null
export -f remote_connect
< CVE-2011-2767-hostsList.txt  xargs -P15 -n1 -d'\n' bash -c 'remote_connect "$@"' --
printf "|$marker|\n"
```

Result:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|Hostname    | RedHat Vesrion | Perl Version                    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|fsx1241     | 6.9            | mod_perl-2.0.4-12.el6_10.x86_64 | 
|fsx1242     | 6.9            | mod_perl-2.0.4-12.el6_10.x86_64 |
|fsx1243     | 6.9            |                                 |
|fsx1244     |                |                                 |
|fsx1245     |                |                                 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [PARAMETER Expansion of Bash](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value) by using a default value. For an example, provide in the bash wiki page, for an example below ..

`${PARAMETER:-WORD}`

`${PARAMETER-WORD}`

Where, If the parameter `PARAMETER` is unset (never was defined) or null (empty), this one expands to `WORD`, otherwise it expands to the value of `PARAMETER`, as if it just was `${PARAMETER}`. If you omit the `:` (colon), like shown in the second form, the default value is only used when the parameter was **unset**, not when it was empty.

Looking at your code, taking the above in consideration, your below line of code just need minor correction and that should do the Job for you.

```
   if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then
       printf "| %-15s | %-15s | %-35s |\n" "$target_host" "$rhelInfo" "$perlInfo"
   else
       printf "| %-15s | %-15s | %-35s |\n" "$target_host" "${rhelInfo:-?}" "${perlInfo:-?}"
   fi
```

### You will get like below:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|Hostname    | RedHat Vesrion | Perl Version                    |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|fsx1241     | 6.9            | mod_perl-2.0.4-12.el6_10.x86_64 | 
|fsx1242     | 6.9            | mod_perl-2.0.4-12.el6_10.x86_64 |
|fsx1243     | 6.9            |                                 |
|fsx1244     | ?              | ?                               |
|fsx1245     | ?              | ?                               |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

hope this will be usefull.